# Recovering from error in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qeventloop

I'm implementing a system that uses 3 threads (one is GUI, one is TCP client for data acquisition and one analysis thread for calculations).
I'm having a hard time handling an exception for either one. The case that I'm trying to solve now is what happens if some calculation goes wrong, and I need to 'freeze' the system. The problem is that in some scenarios, I have data waiting in the analysis thread's event loop. How can I clear this queue safely, without handling all the events (as I said, something went wrong so I don't want any more calculations done).
Is there a way to clear an event loop for a specific thread? When can I delete the objects safely?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you don't even need to stop the event loop. But having your own queue of messages of your *type* you can clean it.

Comment: Or you can implement an error state in your analysing thread. Once you are in an error state, you skip all (new) calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is somewhat low on details, but I assume you're using a `QThread` and embedding a `QEventLoop` in it?

You can call `QEventLoop::exit(-1)`, which is thread safe.

The value passed to `exit` is the exit status, and will be the value returned from `QEventLoop::exec()`. I've chosen -1, which is typically used to denote an error condition.

You can then check the return code from `exec()`, and act accordingly.

```
class AnalysisThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void run() override
    {
        int res = _loop.exec();
        if (res == -1)
        {
            // delete objects
        }
    }

    void exit()
    {
        _loop.exit(-1);
    }
private:
    QEventLoop _loop;
};
```

Elsewhere, in your exception handler

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch(const CalculationError& e)
{
    _analysis_thread.exit();
}
```